# How can I print ordered facts in my function in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

I have the following facts:
(assert(name "Sara"))
(assert(last_name "Jones"))

I would like to print them in a custom format by calling my function.

I have got this function
(deffunction print-them ()
(bind ?n (find-fact ((?n name)) TRUE))
)
This function binds the found fact to a multi field variable ?n which prints like Fact-1, but I do not know how to print the details of the fact such as name is Sara and last_name is Jones.
Would you be able to help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the data inside an ordered (implied deftemplate) fact using the slot name implied. Alternately you can just use the ppfact function to print that data.

```
CLIPS> (assert (name "Sara"))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (name "Joe"))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> 
(deffunction print-them ()
   (do-for-all-facts ((?n name)) TRUE 
      (println (implode$ ?n:implied))))
CLIPS> (print-them)      
"Sara"
"Joe"
CLIPS> 
(deffunction print-them (?name)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?n ?name)) TRUE 
      (ppfact ?n)))
CLIPS> (print-them name)
(name "Sara")
(name "Joe")
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Hi Gary. Thank you very much for your reply. How can I check if the fact that starts with relation such as name exist in the above example before trying to bind it to ?n ? Thank you.

Comment: In the first example of the print-them function that accepts no arguments, the literal name is used in the do-for-all-facts functions, so only facts starting with the name relation will be listed. In the second example that accepts one argument, the relation name is passed as the argument. In the do-for-all-facts function call, the relations will be restricted to the value of the ?name variable, so if you pass the literal name as the argument, only facts of the relation name will be listed.

Comment: Hi Gary. Thanks again for your comment. The second function is very close to what I need to do, but there is a problem on my side. I might not have a fact that starts with name when I define the function. I also do not want to use deftemplate. Basically I need an if condition that checks that a fact which starts with the passed ?name exists on the system befoe proceeding to the next do-for-all-facts because if it does not, the function shows an error saying Unable to find deftemplate name. I really appreciate your help. This line of code is very simple in other languages but I am stuck here.

Comment: Use (member$ ?name (get-deftemplate-list)) as the if condition.